# How to design Firebase Database for a quotes application?

Tags: android, mysql, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a quotes application which works with SQL database and I want to move to a Firebase Database. Since SQL database is a relational database, I am confused with the correct structure for the application.

In the SQL Database I am using three tables:-

- Authors
- Categories
- Quotes

Each quote has an Author and a Category so the user gets to see a list of authors and can view all quotes by a particular author. He can also see a list of categories and can view all quotes associated with a particular category.

So Quotes table has two foreign keys the reference to Authors table primary key and Categories table primary key.

Can anyone help me out the best possible structure of my application?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Youtube has an excellent video series for SQL developers like yourself which should help you. (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

That being said, here is a very simple structure which would work.

```
root
L authors
  L authorId
    L Author { name, email, etc...}
L quotes
  L quoteId
    L Quote { text, category, author }
```

This structure is very simple and will rely on queries to filter the data you need.

List of Authors

```
Query query = reference.child("authors");
```

List of Quotes by Author

```
Query query  = reference.child("quotes").orderByChild("author").equalTo(authorId);
```

List of Quotes by Category

```
Query query = reference.child("quotes").orderByChild("category").equalTo(category);
```

Comment: how to display list of categories with this structure?

Comment: Have a node: root -> categories -> categoryId:name or categoryname:true depending on whether you want to allow duplicates or not